# Deleteing rows from DataGridView with custom DialogBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What i have done is a user `rightclicks` on a `row`. A menu appears, they choose the `delete` option. But there is no confirmation dialog. How can I use a custom form that i have created. that has `delete,cancel buttons`.
My Code that works;

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.dgvTable.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgvTable.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dgvTable.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    } 
    //Call FrmDelete??
}
```

How can I use the new form, to confirm the delete. I have tried using a `MessageBox`

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("ARE YOU SURE?", "DELETE Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    if (this.dgvTable.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvTable.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dgvTable.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            } 
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
}
```

I know thats probably the easiest option. but I would like to use the new `Delete Form`.

Thanks

Comment: Do the same thing with a custom form. All forms can be shown using `ShowDialog` and return `DialogResult`. It's enough to have some buttons in your custom form to return suitable `DialogResult`.

Comment: `using (var dialog = new FrmDelete()) { var dialogResuit = frmDelete.ShowDialog(); ...`

Comment: What is wrong with the standard MessageBox.ShowDialog? If you need the cancel button you can have it in the MessageBoxButtons enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `DialogResult` property of your new form.

In your new form:

```
void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
   this.Close();
}

void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
   this.Close();
}
```

Then in the main form:

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourDialog dlg = new YourDialog();
    DialogResult dialogResult = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (this.dgvTable.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dgvTable.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dgvTable.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                } 
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change a few lines.

The first to show the form:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = new DeleteForm().ShowDialog();
```

And then check the result is "OK" rather than "Yes":

```
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
```

Finally, `DialogResult.No` will never be returned, so your `else if` should just be `else`.

Comment: Thanks, how can i get it delete the row then from clicking `OK`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if the DeleteForm returns `DialogResult.OK` then you go ahead and delete the row..?